# python2.7 histogram comparison - white background anomaly

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, histogram

my program's purpose is to take 2 images and decide how similar they are.
im not talking here about identical, but similarity. for example, if i take 2 screenshots of 2 different pages of the same website, their theme colors would probably be very similar and therefor i want the program to declare that they are similar.

my problem starts when both images have a white background that pretty much takes over the histogram calculation (over then 30% of the image is white and the rest is distributed).

in that case,  the cv2.compareHist (using correlation method, which works for the other cases) gives very bad results, that is, the grade is very high even though they look very different.

i have thought about taking the white (255) off the histogram before comparing, but that requires me to calculate the histogram with 256 bins, which is not good when i want to check similarity (i thought that using 32 or 64 bins would be best)

unfortunately i cant add images im working with due to legal reasons

if anyone can help with an idea, or code that solves it i would be very grateful

thank you very much

Comment: Instead of removing pure white, just remove the highest bin of your histogram, no matter whether there are 32 or 64 bins.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the white color,  rebin the histogra and then compare:

- Compute a histrogram with 256 bins.
- Remove the white bin (or make it zero).
- Regroup the bins to have 64 bins by adding the values of 4 consecutive bins.
- Perform the compareHist().

This would work for any "predominant color". To generalize, you can do the following:

Compare full histrograms. If they are different, then finish.
If they are similar, look for the predominant color (with a 256-bin histogram), and perform the procedure described above, to remove the predominant color from the comparisson.